# Data Network mode doesn't get activated on gingerbread 2.3.4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, 3g, data-connection

This happened all of a sudden. I could not start the 3g on my phone.

The Data Network mode is always deactivated now.

Although, when I go to Settings > Wireless and network settings > Mobile network settings,
the Use packet data option is checked.

Unchecking this option and checking again doesn't work.

Installing the internet settings again from the service provider also didn't help.

Restarting the phone didn't help.

Restoring factory settings didn't help.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do not know if you got it sorted but I had the same problem and did this:

- Tap Settings > Wireless and Networks > **Mobile networks** > **Access Point Names**
- Then tap on one of the relevant APN's pertaining to your provider, such as, for example O2 Mobile Web (Pre-pay or contract)
- Set the APN Type to '*internet,mms*'
- Tap on Menu, tap on 'Save'.

Back out of the **Access Point Names** screen, back out to **Mobile networks**, then:

- Tap on *Packet data* (In some ROMs this could be labeled as *Data Enabled*), and also, *Data roaming* to turn them off.
- Turn those two options back on

And voila its working again!

Comment: Are you sure, that APN Type is set to 'internet,mms', what about 'default,supl,mms'?

Comment: "Access point names" is greyed out if you aren't on GSM/UMTS...

Answer (score 0):

Try to put another sim in the handset and see, you will get it.

Answer (score -2):

Edit the APN entry (see mel's answer) and delete the `SUPL` and `MMS` fields.  Select `default` for the type and  then your data will work.

Comment: I fixed it, but -1 because I'm pretty sure this won't work -- you don't know what carrier the OP has or if these entries even exist.